# Isoperimetric inequality via Crofton's formula

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

I have seen various assertions that one can derive the isoperimetric inequality in the plane from Crofton's formula in geometric probability.  Unfortunately, I have not managed to figure out such a proof (or find a reference containing said proof).  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen an argument using just Crofton's formula, but there's a proof at the end of these slides which uses some more general results from geometric probability: http://www.math.utah.edu/~treiberg/IntGeomSlides.pdf

Answer (score 4):

A proof of the isoperimetric inequality using Crofton's formula is contained in these notes by Treibergs: http://www.math.utah.edu/~treiberg/isoperim/isop.pdf

See also the proof in [Integral Geometry and Geometric Probability](https://books.google.de/books?id=xq1iiumncV4C&pg=PA104&dq=santalo+integral+%22new+proof%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwienOKRkafSAhWBVBQKHZjQBSQQ6AEIQjAF#v=onepage&q=santalo%20integral%20%22new%20proof%22&f=false) by Santalo.

Answer (score 3):

See the below [beautiful note of Chris Croke's.](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~ccroke/dvi-papers/hemis.pdf)

*Christopher B. Croke*, MR 2361884 [**A synthetic characterization of the hemisphere**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-07-09196-4), *Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.* **136** (2008), no. 3, 1083--1086 (electronic).]